# exploding war with spring context

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I have web - app, where I using spring like a base project configure, Hibernate - persistance provider, JPA - to acces the db.
I can not uderstand why I have java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception. I have all libraries in war - archive.

More clearly: There is listener class in which I have exception:

```
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
private GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx;

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
    String springFileConfig = context.getInitParameter("spring-file-config");

    ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load(springFileConfig);
    ctx.refresh();
}
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

}
public static GenericXmlApplicationContext getGenericXmlApplicationContext() {  
    return new AppContextListener().ctx;
}
}
```

There is war archive in intellij:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XwQq.png)

Comment: Which class is "not found"? From which jar should it be drawn?

Comment: It is GenericXmlApplicationContext class

Comment: In my project structure: Maven: org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.5.RELEASE2